# Css make a grid with centered content

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to create a layout for print content on sticker label.
So, I create div and use `display:grid;` to divide space as I want.
The item1, item2, and item3 should overlap each other and centered in the cell.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: 70mm; // Seems useless
  align-items: center;
}

.cell {
  border-style: dashed;
  width: 100mm;
  height: 70mm;
  align-content: center;
}

.item1 {
  z-index: 0;
  width: 40mm;
  height: 40mm;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}

.item2 {
  z-index: 1;
  width: 20mm;
  height: 20mm;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
}

.item2 {
  z-index: 2;
  width: 10mm;
  height: 10mm;
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="cell">
    <div class="item1"></div>
    <div class="item2"></div>
    <img class="item3" src="./src.png" />

  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <div class="item1"></div>
    <img class="item2" src="./src.png" />
    <div class="item3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <div class="item1"></div>
    <img class="item2" src="./src.png" />
    <div class="item3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I can't achieve the correct result: A grid with items centered horizontally AND vertically in each cell. The cell should have precise size (100mmx70mm), 2 cells per row since the page should be printed.

Is there any `CSS` wizard in the audience that can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is `absolute` positioning and `translate` transformations based on percentage.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: 70mm; // Seems useless
  align-items: center;
}

.cell {
  border-style: dashed;
  width: 100mm;
  height: 70mm;
  align-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

.cell>*{
  position: absolute;
  left:50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

.item1 {
  z-index: 0;
  width: 40mm;
  height: 40mm;
  background-color: red;
}

.item2 {
  z-index: 1;
  width: 20mm;
  height: 20mm;
  background-color: blue;
}

.item2 {
  z-index: 2;
  width: 10mm;
  height: 10mm;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="cell">
    <div class="item1"></div>
    <div class="item2"></div>
    <img class="item3" src="./src.png" />

  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <div class="item1"></div>
    <img class="item2" src="./src.png" />
    <div class="item3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <div class="item1"></div>
    <img class="item2" src="./src.png" />
    <div class="item3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you mean for your second item2 selector to be item3?

Comment: This solution is really good for me. Still some issues like the width of the cell that is 70mm instead of 100mm for some reason and the item1 which is a img into a div that is not correctly positionned, but it's a big step in the right direction! Thx!

Comment: @serg Chernata : Sorry, it was a typo of me, the `img` item should be the last one in all cells

Comment: @nimbusparis that really doesn't matter, it has no effect on the solution.